# mod_pagespeed outputs stats but does nothing

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I can see output stats with mod_pagespeed but it does not seam to be doing anything (all stats values stay at 0).

```
serf_fetch_request_count: 0
serf_fetch_bytes_count: 0
serf_fetch_time_duration_ms: 0
serf_fetch_cancel_count: 0
```

Anyone knows what can be going wrong?

Comment: @skaffman lol, thks... you're just too fast. I've seen several people asking for this over the net http://groups.google.com/group/mod-pagespeed-discuss/browse_thread/thread/e7a743c757120184 and thought SO was a good place to leave a proper answer. Didn't tag it as Apache yet precisely not to bother the other users... :)

Comment: FYI, you can contact us at mod-pagespeed-discuss@googlegroups.com and list issues at http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/list

Comment: @sligocki thank you. Actually I've done that, prior to writing on SO. It's great to see you guys roaming SO. `mod-pagespeed` is already one of my favorite tags! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was able to found the blaming lines on my config:

```
// does NOT work with mod_pagespeed 
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$"> 
   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
</FilesMatch>
```

So if you have some fancy DEFLATE options, disable them. On the other hand the below code works.

```
// does WORK with mod_pagespeed 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml font/ 
opentype font/truetype font/woff
```